# Send arbitrary local jars to YARN container classpath

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-twill

I'm using Apache Twill (v 0.10) to build YARN application. I've observed that the jars which are not referenced by my application code are not picked up and sent to containers' classpath. I checked YarnTwillPreparer class to see how the dependencies are decided. However, I'm still not very clear what I need to do to force some additional jars to be sent to each of the YARN containers.

I think there must be a simple and elegant way to achieve that. A precise code snippet is more welcome. Any pointer would also be good.

Comment: Typically, I use Maven to create and submit a shaded jar for YARN

Comment: From the quickstart guide, did you read about the BundledJar runner?